# String Striping React Native

Tags: javascript, string, react-native

I am trying to strip part of a string in react native. And I am getting an error saying that String.slice() method cannot read from an undefined.

<TextInput style={styles.largeFormInput}
onChange={(event) => {

```
          let value = event.target.value;
          setBio(value.slice(0, 10));
        }}

        value={bio} name={"bio"}
        placeholder={"Brief Biography (i.e. hobbies, family life, welness tools & programs that work for you)"} placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle} />
```

{/* was expecting the string to strip correctly and it works fine on web, but it does not work on my expo go simulator */}

Answer (score 1):

There's no `onChange` listener in TextInput.

You should be using `onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}` as per
[ref-doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)

Answer (score 0):

try use `onChangeText` instead of `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

The `event.target.value` is `undefined`. You have to use `onChangeText`

```
onChangeText={(value) => setBio(value.slice(0, 10))}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also learned that there is maxLength attribute in React Native now.